# Right align out the Float Property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.header {
  display: flex
}

.logo,
.contribute,
.class 1,
.class 2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <nav </nav>
    <div class="contribute">
    </div>
    <div class="class 1">
    </div>
    <div class="class 2">
    </div>
</header>
```

In this suppose `.header` has `display: flex;` set.

`.logo`, `.contributor`, `.class 1`, `.class 2` has `display: inline-block;` set and are child to parent `.header` class, which is flex.

How can we make sure that the `.class 1` and `.class 2` are right aligned without using the flow property?

Comment: where is css code? share it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-left: auto;` for class1

```css
div,
nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="logo">1</div>
    <nav></nav>
  </div>
  <div class="contribute">2</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="class1">3</div>
    <div class="class2">4</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Code is updated. But you need to bundle the elements on the right and left.

Comment: I am a nw comer if you think that this question was good then please motivate me by upvoting. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to bundle anything

Comment: @AdiYogi You've been a _new comer_ for 7 months now :) .. so time to stop asking users all the time to upvote your questions. They usually do if they find it _upvoteable_

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `margin-left: auto;` to `.class1` and it will push itself and `.class2` to the right

*I fixed your class names as CSS isn't happy with a class name of only one digit, like the `1` in `class 1`, so either remove the space (which I did in below sample) or add i.e. `nr` (`nr1`). Also, as the items in a flex container is flex items, the `display: inline-block` will have no effect.*

```css
.header {
  display: flex
}

.class1 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
  logo
  </div>
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <div class="contribute">contribute
  </div>
  <div class="class1">class 1
  </div>
  <div class="class2">class 2
  </div>
</header>
```